# GCP: How can I find Instances running for a specific time?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I try to identify all instances running in my Google Cloud Plattform environment for longer than a certain time period specified by me. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 gcloud compute instances list --filter="creationTimestamp.date('%s', Z)< $(date -d'5 hours ago' +%s)" --format="csv[no-heading](NAME)"
```

This should list you all instances running for e.g. more than 5 hours.